# Admin Javascript not loading certain scripts

Tags: control-panel, javascript, cp-themes

It appears that something has changed in the last two weeks that is not allowing the admin javascript to load when updating or creating entries of specific channels because of the field types contained. This is on EE 3.5.17, and no updates done after February. Last operation was 17 May when it was known to work.

The offending cp javascript:
/admin.php?S==cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&plugin=ee_table_reorder&file=cp/global_end,cp/files/picker,cp/grid,fields/file/cp,fields/relationship/cp,cp/date_picker&v=version_number

What I have found is that if I paste in the javascript as-is, it presents the 404, but if I remove the fields/relationship/cp, the cp/grid, and the cp/date_picker, it will load. Adding any of the above theme js back in gives it a 404, even though the files are confirmed in the themes' js/compressed folder. This stops features like grid file upload, etc from working on entry creation / edit pages in the CP.

It was known and confirmed working 2 weeks ago... Any thoughts on why CP javascript behaviour would change in this way?

Comment: As an update, this was caused by Mod Security, which seems to have not liked some parts of the call to back end resources. Our hosting service, A Small Orange, got us back on track by whitelisting the resources.

Comment: I had the same problem with a fresh install of EE 5.2.2 the problem is caused by PHP-FPM switching to PHP-CGI saved the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Small Orange, our great hosting service, reviewed the Mod Security logs and identified the part that was causing this issue to occur. Effectively, there were parts of the URL that were flagged as potential problems and had started blocking them. They were quick to whitelist the resources called in the scripts used, and now our CP's javascript shows up and functions correctly. When it was 404, it was the base script for all the other things like date picker, grid, and other functionality to work right, so without it, things like file upload could not trigger correctly.